# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight') | Angular 11

Tags: angular, scroll

I really hope that some of you could help me to resolve this head-scratcher. I need to have the scrollHeight of the page, but I get just 1/3 of that.

```
setSize() {
    let DOMScrollable = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("div[data-scroll]");
    document.body.style.height = DOMScrollable.scrollHeight + "px";
}

console.log(this.dataScroll.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
// 1177
```

Analyzing the `DOMSrollable.nativeElent`, the real size of `scrollHeight` is 4587. So, using the function above I can't go down, because the scroll stops on 1177px.

Here's an abstraction of (my Typescript/Angular 12) what I'm dealing with. This is the HTML (On my page I have 8 images)

```
<main main>
  <div data-scroll #dataScroll>
        <div class="page">
            <header>
                    <h1>Oceans</h1>
                    <img src="../assets/images/header.jpg" alt="">
            </header>
            <div class="grid">
                <a href="#" class="item item_v">
                    <div class="item__image">
                            <img src="../assets/images/1.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="item__meta">December 23, 2020</div>
                    </div>

                    <h2 class="item__title">Octopus punches fish in the head (just because it can)</h2>
                    <p>Octopuses sometimes partner with fish to hunt, but the partnership comes with risks (for the fish, that is).</p>
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead of `scrollHeight`. e.g.:

```
setSize() {
    let DOMScrollable = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("div[data-scroll]");
    const rect = DOMScrollable.getBoundingClientRect();
    document.body.style.height = rect.height + "px";
}

console.log(rect.height)
// 4587
```

Comment: Thanks to answer me, anyway I tried your solution, but the result doesn't change, the function returns 1177.25 px. Then the scroll stops to 1177.25px